# How to convert Image Data type from imageUrl

Tags: flutter

I need to convert this watermark(from assets) image and imageurl(getting from API) to Image data type, because ui.drawImage takes only Image data types

```dart
 ui.Image? watermarkImage = ui.decodeImage('assets/images/watermark.png');// getting error
    ui.Image? lookbookImage = ui.decodeImage(imageurl); // getting error
    final originalImage = imgData;
    ui.Image image = ui.Image(160, 50);
    ui.drawImage(image, watermarkImage);
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the image bytes

```dart
// network
final response = await http.Client().get(Uri.parse(imageurl));
final bytes = response.bodyBytes;

//assets
final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/watermark.png');
final bytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
```

Then you can decode `ui.Image` from the image bytes

```dart
final image = await decodeImageFromList(bytes);
```

Comment: first of all Thanks for answering @Mohammed
I'm getting error while downloading image 
```flutter
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/images/watermark.png' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

Comment: File cannot be found can occur for two reasons, 1- the file isn't in the specified directory, 2- the file isn't added to `pubspec.yaml` as assets.

Comment: In assets i have added like this:-
```flutter
 assets: - assets/images/ –
```